# Find an element by not exact id

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an element with id looking like the following:

```
some_id_123456_some_id_id_id
```

where `123456` is an arbitrary number which is unknown. How do I find this element by id?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this by combining the both attribute [`starts with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`ends with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector,

```
$('[id^=some_id][id$=_some_id_id_id]')
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe are you missing an `_` at end of `[id^=some_id]` as OP wants `some_id_123456_some_id_id_id` ? As you see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AvyLJ/), `id` `some_id123456_some_id_id_id` also gets selected, which should not as per OP's requirements.

Comment: Since the OP provided pseudo-code Raj's answer is perfectly acceptable @GaurangTandon

Comment: I guess somebody just doesn't like you very much ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jquery selectors for this:

Combine [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and [Attribute Starts With Selector selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^=some_id][id$=_some_id_id_id]')
```